# Changing a link-style, only for a certain class

Tags: html, css

I want to change the link-style for some of my links, like this:

```
a:hover
{
    /* These links will be blue when hovered-over */
    background-color: #3366FF;
}
```

However, I only want this to take effect in my Navigation Bar, and not for regular links.

I have tried variations on this:

```
#navbar a:hover
{
    /* These links will be blue when hovered-over */
    background-color: #3366FF;
}
```

With the intended meaning "this only applies to links with `<div id="navbar">`"
But it didn't work.

How can I set the style for only certain links, defined by the `class` or `id` of their container?

Comment: This is perfectly right, but there are often problems with specificity (rules overriding rules). Can you show the HTML in question?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your second selector, it should work. Use Firebug to see what other selectors are applying background-color to the links.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe your tested links are visited links.
I prefer:

```
#navbar a:hover,
#navbar a:visited
{
    background-color: #3366FF;
}
```

Comment: You are right, it does seem important to specify the behavior for both hover and visited together.  Otherwise it didn't work right.

Answer (score 16):

That looks ok to me, Robusto has a valid point with the colour used.

Another method is giving the links a class of their own, eg:

**CSS**

```
a.navlink:visited 
a.navlink:hover
{
    background-color: #3366FF; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="index.html" class="navlink">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use the "color" property here instead of "background-color".

If by chance you really *do* want to change the background-color, remember that links display inline and don't have a large, comfortable rectangle around them, so depending on the container's background color it might not be noticeable. (This is probably not the case, but I threw that in in case your links are very small.)

Finally, since blue is close to the default link color, consider testing with an exotic color (like red) to see if the problem is in your CSS or your color selection.